# Tomcat not detecting changes to java file at all or automatically

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, updating

I am running Eclipse enterprise version 2019-06 and Tomcat v9.0. I am trying to run a Spring MVC project. Tomcat will not detect changes to the controller classes. It does notice changes to the JSP files though I have to manually restart the server for them to take effect.

First, I am wanting the server to notice changes in the Java classes themselves, even with restarts

Second, I am wondering how to get the server to auto-detect these changes (both class and JSP changes) so that there is not a need to manually reloading the server.

I have tried:

I have ensured that 'Automatically publish when resources change' is selected in the Publishing subsection of Tomcat

I have ensured that under Modules, the Auto-Reloading is not enabled

(Yes, I have tried 'turning it off and back on'. I have deselected and changed the selections as noted above to others and restarted only to change them back again with nothing happening.)

Comment: How are you launching Tomcat? What kind of changes to the controller classes are you making that aren't noticed? Do you have automatic building enabled?

Comment: Tomcat is launching. It is not noticing any changes such as changing what a print line prints.